# Multidimensional for google chart

Tags: php, google-visualization

I been playing around with google chart for my project, and somehow I'm still cant figure out displaying multidimensional array (from database).

print_r() output:

```
Array
    (
 [0] => Array
    (
        [year] => 2000
        [value] => 2766
        [typeName] => Oil
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [year] => 2000
        [value] => 3098
        [typeName] => Gas
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [year] => 2000
        [value] => 269814
        [typeName] => Coal
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [year] => 1999
        [value] => 2836
        [typeName] => Oil
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [year] => 1999
        [value] => 3150
        [typeName] => Gas
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [year] => 1999
        [value] => 257561
        [typeName] => Coal
    )
);
```

as [google chart](https://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?type=visualization#line_chart) required data format, I want it to be something like this:

```
     ['Year' , 'Oil', 'Gas', 'Coal']

     ["2000",   2766,  3098, 269814],
     ["1999"    2836,  3150, 257561]
```

Can someone help me how to play around with the multidimensional?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shuld convert this data into json. Just parse in this way to get the desired structure O(n)

```
 $headers = array("year" => 0, "oil" => 1, "gas" => 2, "coal" => 3);
 $response[] = array_map("ucfirst",array_keys($headers));
 foreach($orig_array as $k => $item) {
    $temp_data[$item['year']][0] = (string) $item['year'];
    $temp_data[$item['year']][$headers[$item['typeName']]] = $item['value'];
    if(4==count($temp_data[$item['year']])) $response[] = $temp_data[$item['year']];
 }     

 $json_data = json_encode($response);
 echo($json_data);
```

Comment: gracias!, exactly what im looking for.

Comment: for now, i will play around with this cool algorithm, since the $headers are dynamic, this helps me a lot,

Comment: Hi mr. cardeol, I have a follow-up question,  what if one of $orig_array only have 3 keys? for example, year:2000 only has 'oil and gas' but no 'coal'?, is it possible to do it with array_fill?

Comment: just initialize variables with 0, in this way (after the year)
$temp_data[$item['year']][1] = 0; // oil
$temp_data[$item['year']][2] = 0; // gas
$temp_data[$item['year']][3] = 0; // coal